# Quivers Representations in SUSY gauge theories

Tags: supersymmetry, gauge-theory, branes

I would like to hear some reasons and ideas on how [quivers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quiver_%28mathematics%29) are useful in SUSY gauge theories. There is a nice answer about the case of D-branes [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27400/quivers-in-string-theory) but it is not clear on their appearance in gauge theory independently of the D-branes. More specifically I have heard that quivers can describe BPS states. Is this correct? And why so?

Comment: SUSY quivers are dissected here http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0201205

Comment: An answer can be found at http://www.physicsoverflow.org/27087