# Quiver Mechanics

Tags: string-theory, mathematical-physics, resource-recommendations, representation-theory, supersymmetry

What do you suggest as an essential and introductory set of references in Physics literature for learning quivers? Any textbook?

Comment: It would be really great if you could specify more about why are you are interested in quivers. I mean, are you in quivers because of its relation with ... supersymmetric field theories? string phenomenology? mathematical physics? topological field theory? SCFTs? just the mathematics of quivers? the representation theory of quivers? quiver varieties? ...

Comment: First of all, thanks for your reply and sorry for my late answer. Actually, I am interested in supersymmetric quantum mechanics and SCFTs. More specifically, I am interested in the map between the number of microstates in a specific configuration in SUGRA (e.g. multi-centered black holes) and quivers. I would like to know "how" we compute the generating functions in quivers. Besides, I like to know what kind of physical system quivers represent, what is the physical interactions in each of the Coulomb and Higgs branches...

Comment: @RamiroHum-Sah Actually, I am interested in supersymmetric quantum mechanics and SCFTs. More specifically, I am interested in the map between the number of microstates in a specific configuration in SUGRA (e.g. multi-centered black holes) and quivers. I would like to know "how" we compute the generating functions in quivers. Besides, I like to know what kind of physical system quivers represent, what the physical interactions are in each of the Coulomb and Higgs branches...

Answer (score 2):

> Besides, I like to know what kind of physical system quivers
> represent,

Roughly speaking, quivers describe systems of D-branes. We have two important facts:

1. It is known that D-branes on a given target space $X$ can be described by means of derived categories [[1]](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0307245) [[2]](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9902116). When mathematicians talk about "derived categories" they try to understand the  derived bounded category of coherent sheaves over $X$, denoted by $\mathcal{D}^b(X)$; we can think physically on this object as all the possible possible D-brane bound states, up to the action of the renormalization group flow [[3]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.02880) [[4]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.09205). More precisely, Any object in $\mathcal{D}^b(X)$ can be understood as a bound state of branes and anti-branes subject to the equivalence relation that declares that two ensembles are equivalent if we can perform "tachyon condensation" to go from one to the other [[5]](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0104147).
2. It is also known that D-brane bound states give a microscopic understanding of the black hole entropy within string theory.

By combining the two facts from above, we can conclude that derived categories are relevant to approach the problem of the exact computation the black hole degeneracies of a given black hole.

The key insight is that there are special classes of D-brane systems that can be associated to quivers (that's the achievement of the seminal paper ["D-branes, Quivers, and ALE Instantons"](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9603167)) and under [nice conditions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/268531/quiver-representations-and-coherent-sheaves/268570#268570) we can guarantee that the following is true:

$$D^b(\mathsf{Coh}(X))\simeq D^b(\mathsf{Rep}(Q)).$$

Then we conclude that when is possible to associate a quiver $Q$ to a D-brane system (such as black holes are) we can understand all its microstates by means of quiver representations.

> I am interested in the map between the number of microstates in a specific configuration in SUGRA (e.g. multi-centered black holes) and quivers.

This is a question that can only be answered case by case. The most common one is the case of an extremal black hole in $\mathcal{N}=2, d=4$ supergravity. The chapter 2 of the [Tudor Dan Dimofte PhD thesis](https://s3.cern.ch/inspire-prod-files-2/20d94b1def4f684392a713f2f177125b) is an excellent overview of the basic ideas.

My advice is try to understand the basics of the following (very pedagogical!) references; the first one explicity work out how to understand the higgs and coulomb branches of some simple quivers:

[Quantum Quivers and Hall/Hole Halos](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0206072)

[Split States, Entropy Enigmas, Holes and Halos](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0702146)

Answer (score 1):

Try *Quiver Representations and Quiver Varieties* by Alexander Kirillov Jnr.

There are not many textbooks on "Quivers" since it is a highly specialized topic in String Theory and SUSY field theories. Also, see [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27400/quivers-in-string-theory) and links therein to papers on the subject by Douglas and Witten.